# How to change order of letters in every word beside first and last letter in sentence in RUST?

Tags: rust

I need to change order of letter in every word of sentence besides first and last letter (example:"According, researcher" =>  "Accroidng, rseaecrehr" or "University, it doesn't matter" => "Uinevsrtiy, it deosn't mtaetr"). I have constant of separators to split my string on words. Semicolon, comma or other separator must be saved.

```
const SEPARATORS: &str = " ,;:!?./%*$=+)@_-('\"&1234567890\r\n";
```

Someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Give more examples, you say "besides last letter", but every last letter of words is changed

Comment: Alex Larionov, thanks for notice, I've edited question.

Comment: Is your character set restricted to only ASCII, or do you need to handle the full breadth of Unicode? Also... what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky since strings are encoded in UTF8 format, you can't just shuffle the bits.  Here's what I came up with:

```
// Random stuff for shuffling the letters
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

// Regex to simplify finding words
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let test = "University, it doesn't matter";
    // If you need a specific subset, you could change the Regex
    // I'm just grabbing consecutive alphabetic characters which should accomplish the same thing
    let re = Regex::new("[[:alpha:]]+").unwrap();
    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    // First change our &str into a mutable Vec<char>
    let mut char_array: Vec<char> = test.chars().collect();

    // Then use the regex to iterate through each "word" found
    re.find_iter(test).for_each(|m| {

        // Carefully reduce the size of the "word" by one on each side
        let mut range = m.range();
        if range.start + 1 < range.end {
            range.start += 1
        }
        if range.end - 1 >= range.start {
            range.end -= 1
        }

        // Shuffle the portion of the character array that represents the inner letters of the "word"
        char_array[range].shuffle(&mut rng);
    });

    // Finally we put it all back into a string
    let r: String = char_array.iter().collect();

    // TADA!!
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

Comment: Sean, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sean, but how can I do this without regular expressions ?

Comment: I prefer to use Regex when possible as it is a _very_ powerful tool in the toolbox, here's a non-regex version though.  [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bbcc6b9ddda7d6bf7ea1ee71c6a63cde)